# Running sparklyr in Google Colab

Tags: r, installation, bigdata, google-colaboratory, sparklyr

I'm not sure if there is a possibility to install and use `sparklyr` within Google Colab to run my analyzes using R.

Is there any other R package that runs large volumes of data like spark within R that works in Colab?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get `sparklyr` in colab, there's several articles/posts I read through but [this](https://grabngoinfo.com/install-pyspark-3-on-google-colab-the-easy-way/) was most helpful. I know it says `PySpark` but it works in R runtime as well.

```
# Download Java Virtual Machine (JVM)
system("apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null")

# Download Spark
system("wget -q https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.3.1/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz")

# Unzip the file
system("tar xf spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz")

# setup the environment for spark 
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64")
Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/content/spark-3.3.1-bin-hadoop3")

install.packages("sparklyr")

install.packages("arrow") # optional but recommended for speed boosts

spark_install()
```

That should do it.